# We fell In love and we wanted to get married. Can I be very clear there was no haram between us! He was murdered, will Allah unite us in jannat?

Tags: love

I met a man whom I fell in love with and he loved me too. We did not make a haram relationship, instead we waited so he could buy a house and marry me. We did not see each other a lot because we wanted to do it the right way. I last saw him just before he was murdered. I miss speaking to him and I feel sad that he is gone because he was the only person I had in my life that genuinely loved and cared for me. My question is, will we be United in jannat?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is a hadith: **"You will be with those Whom you love"**. I give the hadith below:

> A man asked the Prophet (ﷺ) about the Hour (i.e. Day of Judgment)
> saying, "When will the Hour be?" The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "What have you
> prepared for it?" The man said, "Nothing, except that I love Allah and
> His Apostle." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "You will be with those whom you
> love." We had never been so glad as we were on hearing that saying of
> the Prophet (i.e., "You will be with those whom you love.") Therefore,
> I love the Prophet, Abu Bakr and `Umar, and I hope that I will be with
> them because of my love for them though my deeds are not similar to
> theirs.
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 3688]

If you die with **Imaan** and he did also, then *inshaAllah*, you will meet with him in jannah(as we learn from this hadith). The rest Allah knows....

Comment: If my answer is correct to you then you can **accept** my answer by clicking the **tick** button below the voting buttons. So that others will understand that my answer is correct